# How can I remove an autostart service that is not listed in gnome-session-properties?

Tags: 13.10, autostart

Today I upgraded from raring to saucy. This brought the Ubuntu One icon back to my indicator applet, which I had disabled.

So I removed the line `NoDiplay=true` from `/etc/xdg/autostart/ubuntuone-launch.desktop`.

But still Ubuntu One doesn't show up in gnome-session-properties and I can't disable it.

What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I had a `ubuntu-launch.desktop` file in my `~/.config/autostart` that specified the entry as hidden, overwriting the global file in /etc/xdg/autostart. I removed this file. Afterwards I could disable Ubuntu One in gnome-session-properties as expected.